# Integer -> Double -> String

Tags: haskell

I am not sure, I understand this:

```
f :: Integer -> Double -> String -> String
f a d s = undefined
```

What can the potential body of `f` be here? I am confused by this new syntax never encountered before.

**EDIT:** So, since `a` is an `Integer`, and `d` is a `Double`, can the body of the method be written as such, that a `String` is returned depending on the type? Like a comparison.

**Python:**

```
def f(a: int, d: float, s: str) -> str:
  if(s == "Is Integer less than Double"):
    if(a < d):
      return "Yes, it is."
    else:
      return "No, it isn't"
```

**How to do the same in Haskell?**

Comment: Have you ever learned about a function with more than one argument?

Comment: Haskell, is strange. I understand other programming languages, I am familiar with multi-paramters.

Comment: Have you learned about functions in Haskell that have more than one parameter? If you are learning Haskell from a book, you probably should have learned them before you found this code.

Comment: No. I am newbie. And I am confused by: `Integer -> Double -> String -> String`

Comment: I could tell you, but the next thing would probably confuse you as well. Can I suggest: learn Haskell?

Comment: I am learning Haskell currently, but, thought, I post here with regard to this part.

Comment: so I am wondering: did you learn about functions that have more than one parameter, before you got to this question in the book?

Comment: In C++, it would be: `std::string f(int a, double x, std::string s) { ...BODY RETURNING SOME STRING VALUE...}`

Comment: “What can the potential body of `f` be here?” – well, `f a d s = ""` would certainly be a possible definition, albeit a rather useless one. What do you want the function to do? If you can write how you'd do it in another language, perhaps Java and Python, we can answer how to translate that to Haskell.

Comment: Yes, C++ is 100% easier to understand, and I've used it for many years, way too long.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, please see my **EDIT** !

Comment: This is not clarifying the question. There are a myriad of ways a function with this signature could be implemented. Again, just say how you'd approach it in another language, then the question becomes clearly answerable.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I added a **Python** example.

Comment: Sounds like troll question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could actually translate your Python code, mapping the syntactic structure almost literally to Haskell. What changes is

- You don't need `return` (because in Haskell you always directly specify what the function returns, and only need extra syntax for managing monadic side effects – which this function doesn't have).
- On the flip side, you *do* need to have an `else` in every `if` statement, because unlike in Python you can't just *not return anything* (well, arguably you can't do that in Python either, it just defaults to returning `None` if you don't explicitly return something else).
- You can't directly use `<` on two different typed variables. Unlike Python, Haskell never does automatic type conversion, however you can explicitly do it with `fromIntegral`.

So,

```
f a d s =
   if(s == "Is Integer less than Double")
     then if(fromInteger a < d)
       then "Yes, it is."
       else "No, it isn't"
     else {- ...whatever should happen in this case -}
```

Haskellers tend to not use `if` constructs though, but instead use *guards* for conditionals, i.e.

```
f a d s
 | s == "Is Integer less than Double"
    = if(fromInteger a < d)
       then "Yes, it is."
       else "No, it isn't"
 | otherwise = {- ...whatever should happen in this case -}
```

That actually allows you to also omit the explicit fallback case, though the compiler will then warn about an incomplete match.

Anyway it's still not idiomatic: Haskellers avoid binding a function argument just to check it for equality. Instead, you just *pattern match* on the value you compare against:

```
f a d "Is Integer less than Double"
    = if(fromInteger a < d)
       then "Yes, it is."
       else "No, it isn't"
f a d s = {- ...whatever should happen in this case -}
```

Now you can actually use guards for what was originally the inner `if`:

```
f a d "Is Integer less than Double"
 | fromInteger a < d
              = "Yes, it is."
 | otherwise  = "No, it isn't"
f a d s = {- ...whatever should happen in this case -}
```

If you really don't want to handle the case of any other string, then you should make that a *failure case* that's expressed also through the type signature:

```
f :: Integer -> Double -> String -> Maybe String
f a d "Is Integer less than Double"
 | fromInteger a < d
              = Just "Yes, it is."
 | otherwise  = Just "No, it isn't"
f _ _ _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, since `a` is an `Integer`, and `d` is a `Double`, can the body of the method be written as such, that a String is returned depending on the type? Like a comparison.

Yess, there is however a small caveat. The [**`(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60-) requires that the two operands have the same type, so we will need to convert for example the `Integer` to a double first, we can do this with [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) to convert it to any type that is a member of the `Num` typeclass.

We can implement this with *guards* as:

```
f :: Integer -> Double -> String -> String
f a d "Is Integer less than Double"
  | fromInteger a < d = "Yes, it is."
  | otherwise = "No, it isn't"
```

The function is however not *total*, only if the third parameter is `"Is Integer less than Double"`, then it will thus compare the two. Programmers in Haskell tend to prefer functions that return something for every *possible* input, since then they do not have to worry much about passing certain inputs.

Comment: How can this be done with all three params, nicely they way you showcase it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer -> Double -> String -> String
```

This representation of a function's parameter list is how "Functional Programming" sees functions.

In non-functional languages, we are used to see something like these:

```
String (Integer, Double, String) // C-like prefix types
(Integer, Double, String): String // Python like postfix type
```

But here is the thing: functional languages use that form because you can create partial functions that are not possible in non-functional languages (without specially crafting)

This means all these are valid functions for that signature

```
result1 = f i d s ;;( (Integer->Double->String)->String)

g = f i ;;( (Integer)->(Double->String->String) )
result2 = g d s 

h = f i d ;;( (Integer->Double)->(String->String) )
result3 = h s
```

Until you supply all required parameters, you will get partial functions composed of the ones you provided.

Comment: **Yılmaz Durmaz**, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U66ixhdbxEI 